# ERROR running force:source:retrieve: Flag --manifest expects a value

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode, manifest

I want to retrieve Salesforce data from my trailhead playground. I connect visual studio code with the org by authenticating the source org. I write the following command in terminal:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\sfd\lwcs\manifest>sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest
```

The command shows me the following error:

```
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  Flag --manifest expects a value
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. please help

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can see the metadata on the CLOUD but I don't know how to retrieve that in my project? for example I want the apex classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm), you will notice that the manifest flag `--manifest` or `-x` requires a path to package.xml file `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x "path/to/package.xml"`. Since you are using VS Code, you can also retrieve metadata using the `CLOUD` icon in the left bar and then click the download icon.

To retrieve the classes you can either use the UI or run this:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
```

[image: Retrive code]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can see the metadata on the CLOUD but I don't know how to retrieve that in my project? for example I want the apex classes

Comment: Updated the answer with your query.

Comment: It works. Thank alot